# Trying to use a function written in C in a python script using a shared library. Not sure what error is trying to tell me

Tags: python, c, dll, shared-libraries

```
  1 import ctypes
  3 # Load the shared library
----> 4 lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(r'C:/Coding_Projects/Hough_Proj/C/HoughTransform.dll')
  6 # Declare the function signature (return type and argument types)
  7 lib.HoughTransform.restype = ctypes.c_float

File c:\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py:460, in LibraryLoader.LoadLibrary(self, name)
459 def LoadLibrary(self, name):
--> 460     return self._dlltype(name)

File c:\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py:382, in CDLL.__init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
379 self._FuncPtr = _FuncPtr
381 if handle is None:
--> 382     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
383 else:
384     self._handle = handle

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

I type a command in my terminal that creates two files called HoughTransform.exe and HoughTransform.dll. Where is the issue arising in the process of creating this shared library?